# How to obtain Bearer token from auth0 for tests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, auth0

I'm using Auth0 and securing my api in spring-boot. Is there any way to mock or whatever for testing endpoint for target authority.

I'm using also auth0-spring-security-api for decoding jwt.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to to create a token for your tests

you can do this

```
MvcResult result =
mvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/v1/path/example")
            .with(jwt(token -> token.claim("claimKey","claimValue"))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andReturn();
```

to use this you have to use mock mvc. so annotate your test class with @AutoConfigureMockMvc

and inject MockMvc

@Autowired private MockMvc mvc;

Answer (score -3):

You can take a look at Auth0's documentation on this topic here, it may of be of use to you:
https://auth0.com/docs/dev-lifecycle/local-testing-and-development
https://auth0.com/docs/support/testing